# ValueError: too many values to unpack in Django models

Tags: python, django, testing, models

**Test.py**

The files serves to test everything within the memepost app.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from memepost.models import memepost, memepostForm
from datetime import date 
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class memepostTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        memepost.objects.create(title="foo", 
            model_pic="/site_media/media/pic_folder/casual_headshot.jpg", 
            date=date(2017, 05, 14))
        memepost.objects.create(title="bar", 
            date=date(2017,05, 1))
            
    def test_memepost_enters_database(self):
        foo = memepost.objects.get("foo")
        bar = memepost.objects.get("bar")
        self.assertEqual(foo.date, "6/15/17")
        logger.debug("foo date is equal to %s", foo.date)
        self.assertEqual(bar.model_pic, "no-img.jpg")
        logger.debug("bar is equal to %s", bar.model_pic)
```

**models.py**

This file serves to be scheme for creating memes in my database.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class memepost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    model_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='pic_folder/', default='pic_folder/no-img.jpg')
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class memepostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = memepost
        fields = ["title", "model_pic", "date"]
```

**error**

Okay, so I am getting this warning, but I think the problem has something to do with the title paramater since I call a get function by the title. I hope I was clear.

```
WARNING:py.warnings:/home/ubuntu/workspace/mysiteenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1393:
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField memepost.date received a naive datetime (2017-05-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
          RuntimeWarning)

======================================================================
ERROR: test_memepost_enters_database (memepost.tests.memepostTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/mysite/memepost/tests.py", line 20, in test_memepost_enters_database
    foo = memepost.objects.get("foo")
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/mysiteenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/mysiteenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 378, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/mysiteenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 790, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/mysiteenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 808, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/mysiteenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1243, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/mysiteenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1269, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/mysiteenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1146, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: too many values to unpack

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.007s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing keyword argument for `get` manager method

```
def test_memepost_enters_database(self):
    foo = memepost.objects.get(title="foo")
    bar = memepost.objects.get(title="bar")
    ...
```